# MS SQL Server 2 identical databases on different servers replication or mirroring to each other possible?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql, replication, mirror

Hi: I have one free version of SQL Server 2012 express database running on Amazon AWS with 1 CPU and only 1 GB Ram . As you can see the CPU and RAM power are barely enough for my PHP scripts running on a separate AWS desktop machine to pump data into the server but its free except that I have to pay for data coming in and going out. I have this setup because I need a reliable database that is always on. It has data constantly coming in and I want to achieve the following:

1. In order to keep my outbound data expenses very low and to get high  SQL server performance to I want to replicate my data from the Amazon AWS database to my database running on my personal laptop which is very powerful. This way I can run queries as much as I want without disturbing the little Amazon AWS engine database or incurring heavy data transfer charges. I usually turn off my laptop so constant replication is not possible. Is there a way I can set my replication on my laptop in such a way that as soon as my laptop is switched on and online then it will automatically replicate from when it was switched off and then I can do my stuff? It can even be manual replication and I'm perfectly fine with it.
2. Different scenario: So as I mentioned in the top paragraph that I have PHP scripts running on a separate Amazon AWS Windows desktop that are pumping data into the single CPU 1 GB ram MS SQL server running on a separate AWS instance. On rare occasions these scripts slip up and skip writing data and then my data goes bad. To prevent this I want to have another identical setup with Amazon BUT I want to set these two separate but identical databases to either replicate or mirror with each other so any time data on is changed one database they both synchronize with each other. Is it possible to have two databases be slave master of each other or parallel mirroring with each other? If so then how can I make this happen?

Thanks to all in advance.

Romina.

Comment: "I have one free version of SQL Server 2012 express database" -> then no. Express has zero options for replication or mirroring because it is free.

Answer (score 2):

Point 2, can be addressed by using AWS RDS to back up data for you.

Otherwise, you manually need to create a snapshot of your EC2 instance but this involved a tiny bit of downtime and will cost money to store on S3.

Point 1, just restore the database

Either way, you want a high level of functionality that you don't want to pay for, so our options for helping you are limited.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed -- db mirroring would be highly unlikely in this situation since it works best if it's persistent and would need manual intervention every time you turned your desktop system on. Snapshot Replication is the only realistic option in the replication world, and there's no benefit gained over using a simple database backup and restore or AWS snapshot.